# Kill a script that is started by subprocess call to emulate a key stroke

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running a python script that executes a script using the subprocess module using the popen method. The issue that I am having is that the script that I am calling via popen keeps running even though I have a terminate command. 
Just a note - when I run the .par script by itself the only way to terminate it is sending a keystroke - "e" + return. Question that I have is how I can kill the script after running it for 5 secs. Here is what I have so far -

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import subprocess

pro = subprocess.Popen('/home/xxx/bin/xxy.par', shell=True)
out=pro.communicate()
print out ### this prints out the output of the .par script

pro.terminate() ### this is for killing the .par script
```

output of the .par script as it runs. the way to exit out of the script is to send the keys - e + enter. Else it keeps running and reports the state information continously.

```
------------ [ Press key + <ENTER>: a=Attach, c=Config, d=Detach, e=Exit, l=Analyze, m=Airplane Mode, p=Toggle Ping, q=Toggle QXDM, r=ReAttach, s=ADB Shell ] ------------
I 09:56:26 <phase: control_ue> - RadioState: ON, Airplane Mode: OFF, RegState: REG_HOME, Data: CONNECTED, RAT: LTE, PING: OFF, QXDM: OFF, Battery: 100%
I 09:56:26 <phase: control_ue> -    , RSRP: -86, RSSNR: 30.0, RSRQ: -7, PCI: 24, TAC: 766666, eNB/cellId: ddd
------------ [ Press key + <ENTER>: a=Attach, c=Config, d=Detach, e=Exit, l=Analyze, m=Airplane Mode, p=Toggle Ping, q=Toggle QXDM, r=ReAttach, s=ADB Shell ] ------------
I 09:56:26 <phase: control_ue> - RadioState: ON, Airplane Mode: OFF, RegState: REG_HOME, Data: CONNECTED, RAT: LTE, PING: OFF, QXDM: OFF, Battery: 100%
I 09:56:26 <phase: control_ue> -    , RSRP: -86, RSSNR: 30.0, RSRQ: -7, PCI: 24, TAC: 766666, eNB/cellId: ddd
------------ [ Press key + <ENTER>: a=Attach, c=Config, d=Detach, e=Exit, l=Analyze, m=Airplane Mode, p=Toggle Ping, q=Toggle QXDM, r=ReAttach, s=ADB Shell ] ------------
I 09:56:26 <phase: control_ue> - RadioState: ON, Airplane Mode: OFF, RegState: REG_HOME, Data: CONNECTED, RAT: LTE, PING: OFF, QXDM: OFF, Battery: 100%
I 09:56:26 <phase: control_ue> -    , RSRP: -86, RSSNR: 30.0, RSRQ: -7, PCI: 24, TAC: 766666, eNB/cellId: ddd
------------ [ Press key + <ENTER>: a=Attach, c=Config, d=Detach, e=Exit, l=Analyze, m=Airplane Mode, p=Toggle Ping, q=Toggle QXDM, r=ReAttach, s=ADB Shell ] ------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Killing your script with system facilities**

Assuming you're running on a Posix system (like Linux), you can use signals to terminate your script regardless of the script-specific commands you could use to ask it to exit. The [`terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) method you used sends a `SIGTERM` to your subprocess. It looks like script doesn't exit when it receives that signal. You can send other signals with the [`send_signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal) method. `SIGINT` is typically the signal that would get sent by hitting ctrl-c while your program is running. It is generally considered a good idea to send `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` because the running program can catch those and do any cleanup it wants to. But that also means that it can catch the signal and ignore it altogether. It can't ignore the `SIGKILL` signal (which you can also send with the [`kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) method) so you can use that if other signals aren't working.

The linked documentation explains the different behavior on a Windows system.

Note that since your script is expecting input on stdin, you might have to make sure stdin is connected to a pipe lest it hang waiting for input.

```py
import subprocess
import signal

pro = subprocess.Popen('/home/xxx/bin/xxy.par', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out=pro.communicate()

# Ask your process to exit politely
pro.send_signal(signal.SIGINT) 

# Be more insistent (these are equivalent)
pro.send_signal(signal.SIGKILL)
pro.kill()
```

**Sending the exit command to your script**

Since you script has an exit command you can also communicate with it via `stdin` to send that command. You have to set this up when you make the `Popen` call by connecting `stdin` on your script to a pipe. Then you can send commands to it with the `communcate` method:

```py
import subprocess

pro = subprocess.Popen('/home/xxx/bin/xxy.par', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out=pro.communicate("e")
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. That still does not help. .par script still continues to run. It just seems like the program does not execute beyond out=pro.communicate()

Comment: @rfguy I edited the answer with more details. See if that helps?

Comment: That did not work 100 % like I wanted but I did get a clue so thanks for that. in the end I wrote a wrapper script that calls the first script. Towards the end of the wrapper script I added a new subprocess command to kill the  .par script using the pkill command.